# SFML vscode undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)' and more

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, linker-errors, sfml

I have been trying to install sfml in vscode, I added all lib files to MinGW lib folder and added path to smfl/bin folder in PATH env.

I have downloaded "GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit" version of SFML.

tasks.json:-

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "D:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-I",
            "D:\\setup,cheats,roms,keys\\SFML-2.5.1\\include",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-lsfml-graphics", "-lsfml-window", "-lsfml-system",
            "-DSFML_STATIC",
            "-lsfml-graphics-s", "-lsfml-window-s", "-lsfml-system-s",
            "-lopengl32", "-lwinmm", "-lgdi32", "-lfreetype",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }]
}
```

test_graphics.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world\n";
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Test window");
  while (window.isOpen()) {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

error:-

```
Executing task: D:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.cpp -I D:\setup,cheats,roms,keys\SFML-2.5.1\include -o d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.exe -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -DSFML_STATIC -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lfreetype <

d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg7NkPi.o: 
in function `main':
d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:7: undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c D:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.cpp -I D:\setup,cheats,roms,keys\SFML-2.5.1\include -o d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.exe -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -DSFML_STATIC -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lfreetype" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

I have tried everything linked all libraries specified everywhere, researched a lot, tried god knows how many things, but no luck. Can anybody help me?

Edit:-

I also tried this

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [{
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "D:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-I",
            "D:\\setup,cheats,roms,keys\\SFML-2.5.1\\include",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "-L",
            "D:\\setup,cheats,roms,keys\\SFML-2.5.1\\lib",
            "-DSFML_STATIC",
            "-lsfml-graphics", "-lsfml-window", "-lsfml-system",
            "-lopengl32", "-lwinmm", "-lgdi32", "-lfreetype",
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }]
}
```

error:-

```
Executing task: D:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.cpp -I D:\setup,cheats,roms,keys\SFML-2.5.1\include -o d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.exe -L D:\setup,cheats,roms,keys\SFML-2.5.1\lib -DSFML_STATIC -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lfreetype <

d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\VISHNU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccJQcktP.o: 
in function `main':
d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'     
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:7: undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/c++/test_sfml/test_graphics.cpp:6: undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process "C:\windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c D:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -g d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.cpp -I D:\setup,cheats,roms,keys\SFML-2.5.1\include -o d:\c++\test_sfml\test_graphics.exe -L D:\setup,cheats,roms,keys\SFML-2.5.1\lib -DSFML_STATIC -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lfreetype" terminated with exit code: 1.

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: You should link your code with either the libraries without -s or with -s, but not both.

Comment: ok I tried both with only -s and only without -s and it still gave me same error.

Comment: No -DSFML_STATIC must be specified if no -s in the libs is used.

Comment: It looks like you installed not matching sfml libraries, g++ probably tries to link your code with VS libs.

Comment: @S.M. I have added a new edit in which I have removed libs from MinGW lib folder and specified my own path to lib, and it is still not working, can u look through it?

Comment: @S.M. I have downloaded sfml version:- GCC 7.3.0 MinGW (SEH) - 64-bit, can u help me if this is not the correct sfml libraries to install

Comment: The mingw32 in your compiler path seems to suggest you have a 32 bit compiler, so you need a 32bit sfml as well.

Comment: @Botje thanks, that solved the problem, but I did download the MinGW-w64 but it looks like for some reason I still have a 32-bit compiler.